# How to multiply a column by a constant in csv

Tags: python, csv

I am trying a to multiply the values in a column by 1.5

```
import csv

ids=[2,4,1,10,6,7,15,9]
names=["Joe","Steve","Samantha","Leah","Riley","Ashley","Sheyanne"]
salaries=[95000,35000.150000,99000,53215,23424,225000]

with open("q2.csv","w+",newline='') as file:
    filewriter=csv.writer(file)
    content=[ids,names,salaries]
    zipped=zip(*content)

    fieldnames=["id","name","salary"]

    filewriter.writerow(fieldnames)
    filewriter.writerows(zipped)

with open("q2.csv","r")as fileread:
    reader=csv.reader(fileread)
    next(reader,None)

    listJ=[]
    for row in reader:
        if len(row[1])<=3 or row[1].startswith("S"):
            listJ.append(row)

    for row in listJ:
        row[2]=row[2]*1.5
    print(listJ)
```

It produces a result like this.

```
[['2', 'Joe', '9500095000'], ['4', 'Steve', '35000.1535000.15'], ['1', 'Samantha', '9900099000']]
```

I tried to use

```
for id,name,salary in listJ:
    salary=salary*1.5
```

This one gives me

```
>TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I even tried to use numpy.asarray to make the salaries list float but still doesnt work.

Thanks

Comment: `'35000.1535000.15'` is not a legal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The salary field is read in as a string, so you'll need to convert it first to a numeric type:

```
salary = float(salary) * 1.5
```

Or:

```
row[2] = float(row[2]) * 1.5
```

Comment: @Sheldore, it's not input data, it's a result.

Comment: It worked thanks but do you know how to limit the decimal places in the results? I got ['4', 'Steve', 52500.225000000006]

Comment: Sure, you can format it `"{0:.2f}".format(num)` or use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) type.